# CHECKDB run times issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc-checkdb

When using the PHYSICAL_ONLY option and NOINDEX with CHECKDB, my run times are longer!  But, on the weekend, it is 1/4 the time without those options.  Yes, there are more data changes during the week (like most systems) but from everything I have read using either option (especially both) is supposed to significantly decrease the run time.

Can someone help explain why this seems to be having the opposite affect?  We are running SQL Server 2012 SP2 and Windows 2012.  And I don't see anything obvious (yet) with the other service packs/cu's for SQL Server 2012.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, I am at my wits end here.

Comment: Have you compared weekday/end runtimes *with the same options* to isolate how much your weekday traffic is affecting it? You should upgrade to SP4 regardless.

Comment: What LowlyDBA say. We need to compare apples to apples. Start by using the same options on weekdays and weekends. Compare that. Then try on weekend use both NOINDEX/PHYSICAL_ONLY and compared such a weekend run without those options.

Comment: Thanks but that's been done already, same result.

Comment: I have been so focused on one server I missed the fact we have another server with SP3 (where the CHECKDB "run time" bug was supposedly fixed), and still seeing the same behavior.  Again, at my wits end....

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us those stats or numbers and also show a graphical overview of load when checkDB is running. Also can you confirm if the job actually run on weekdays and weekends at same time? possibly you might be running at different day of intervals